# How to cache JDK and android sdk in github workflow?

Tags: android, github-actions

I want to cache JDK and android SDK in github actions workflow. Everytime it takes too much time to download and install JDK and android sdk. I wrote following steps in workflow:

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 60
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: "zulu"
          java-version: 11

      - name: Setup Android SDK
        uses: android-actions/setup-android@v2
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
```

How can I cache these steps?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options I used for caching.

1. Use [artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#about-workflow-artifacts) inside GitHub. There you have to choose a ID with which you store the artifact and then later using the same ID you can load this artifact.
2. Cache using a docker image. In this case you would move your workflow steps into a Docker image and then use the Docker [build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) to build this image and then you can push cache this image in a registry. As described [here](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/docs/advanced/cache.md#cache). Docker automatically detects which parts of a image it can reuse from the cache. E.g. it will only download Java 11 once and then afterwards use the one from the cache.